# Invoking a class template member function pointer through operator()

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, class-template

I have a set of classes; one is template and accepts the other two classes as its template argument. The class template has a function pointer member that will point to a function of the `T` class. I'm trying to invoke the function call through the class's `operator()()`.

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
template<class T>
class A {
private:
    T* ptrT{ nullptr };
public:
    explicit A( T t ) : ptrT( &t ) {}

    void(T::*func)();

    void operator()() {
        (ptrT->*func)();
    }    
};

class B {
    int ib{2};
public:
    void func() {
        std::cout << ib << '\n';
    }
};

class C {
    int ic{6};
public:
    void func() {
        std::cout << ic << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        B b;
        C c;
        A<B> a1( b );
        A<C> a2( c );
        a1.func = &B::func;
        a2.func = &C::func;

        a1();
        a2();   

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

So far this compiles, however it appears the output is displaying the address of the function pointer, instead of the values...

*-Output-*

```
// 1st Run
20326695
20326703

// 2nd Run
2304295
2304303

// 3rd Run
1780007
1780015
```

I know that to get the actual value I must deference something, but with the syntax for class member function pointers being a little obscure, I don't know what needs to be deferenced nor the proper syntax... I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Your parameter `T t` in `A`'s constructor is passed by value. You are taking and saving the address of the local variable into `ptrT`. The result you get is garbage due to undefined bahavior. I assume it is a typo for `T& t`.

Comment: @user10605163 hmm okay... I'll try to pass by reference instead and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user10605163 That did the trick! I had a feeling it was something simple that I was missing or overlooking. It wasn't a typo; I just wasn't thinking about the local copy being passed into the constructor as opposed to passing by reference. I was more focused on the member function pointer syntax, and overlooked the simpler stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10605163/user10605163) provided in the comments what I was missing. It had nothing to do with the syntax for member function pointers nor how to invoke or deference them to get the correct values.

It was something simple that I had overlooked or missed. The problem or issue was in my class template's constructor. I was passing by value instead of reference and therefor was getting `UB`. It was copying the address of the local copy and saving that into the member pointer. All that had to be changed to fix the above code was this:

I had to change this:

```
explicit A( T t ) : ptrT( &t ) {}
```

to this:

```
explicit A( T& t ) : ptrT( &t ) {}
```

And now everything works as expected and I am now getting the correct results.